# How to use the load() method of useFetcher() in remix.run?

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I was trying to fetch an api route using useFetcher() but unfortunately I couldn't make it work.
Here's what I've tried so far :

```js
// api.time.jsx
// api route returning json response
export const loader = () => {
  return { time: new Date().toLocaleString() };
};
```

```js
// time.jsx
// trying to fetch api route and show data on the page
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useFetcher } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Time() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (fetcher.state === "idle") {
        fetcher.load("http://localhost:3000/api/time");
        console.log(fetcher);
      }
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, 1000);
  }, [fetcher]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Time</h2>
      <p>{fetcher.data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally, the page loads for a second though the `fetcher.data` remains `undefined` and then throws a `404` error.

Comment: err, 404 is quite a specific error that would presumably be unrelated to your method of fetching. Have you confirmed this is due to useFetcher?

Comment: Yes it is, unfortunately.

Comment: What is useFetcher changing your url to, that is causing it to 404? 404 comes from the server, when you request something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Though it seems absurd, it is happening. Maybe any bug? I've been trying for a whole day to figure it out. Can you tell me if there's any wrong in my code logic to fetch `/api/time` route using the useFetcher() hook?

Comment: i don't see a reason to look into whether or not the useFetcher code is correct if you can't yet confirm why the server is giving you a 404. Your dev tools should show you exactly what method and url is used in the request. For all I know, something in the url is misspelled, or should be capitalized, or should have a trailing slash, but it's not all that useful to just guess till it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to load a "route" that doesn't exist. `"http://localhost:3000/api/time"`, as a route, likely isn't a route in your app, but `"/api/time"` is.

Update `fetcher.load("http://localhost:3000/api/time");` to `fetcher.load("/api/time");`.

I think you may also have a stale closure over the `fetcher` value in the interval's callback. Cache `fetcher` in a React ref and access this in the callback.

The cleanup function to clear the interval should also be returned from the `useEffect` hook's callback, not the interval's callback.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useFetcher } from "@remix-run/react";

export default function Time() {
  const fetcher = useFetcher();
  const fetcherRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetcherRef.current = fetcher;
  }, [fetcher]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (fetcherRef.current.state === "idle") {
        fetcherRef.current.load("/api/time");
        console.log(fetcherRef.current);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [fetcher]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Time</h2>
      <p>{fetcher.data}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```